# Cannot load past boot screen

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer won't start, it reaches to the boot screen then tells you to restart, I tried formatting it, but it keeps freezing up at various stage go it won't start up or anything..It only reaches the boot screen, can someone help me?

I tried formatting both hard drives and it's the same problem, I also switched the cable from the hard drives to see if that is the problem but it keeps freezes and various stages when been formatted.

I also want to know if it is a software or hardware problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem occurs after a reformat or during OS installation, it is most likely a hardware issue.

If you have a portable OS (LiveCD or similar) and can run that to test, that may be beneficial. Each piece of hardware you can exclude or test in another system (hard drives, RAM, video card) will help diagnose what the issue is.

If you have an OS installed, and can boot in safe mode (or partially boot and note the error), that again will contribute (hold F8 during boot to trigger the menu). If no OS is installed, trying to install and seeing where it fails will help somewhat.

Comment: Here is a good portable OS [Gparted](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=gparted)